# Use List of custom Business Objects as ComboBox datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generic-collections

I have class like this:

```
class MyClass     {
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }

    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }

public MyClass(int i, string s)
{
    FirstProperty = s;
    SecondProperty = i;
}   

        }
```

and a Winform with code like this:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass(1, "ABC"));
myList.Add(new MyClass(2, "ZXC"));

comboBox1.DataSource = myList;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "FirstProperty";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SecondProperty";
```

When I execute this code it fauls with "Cannot bind to new display member".
This has worked for me in the past. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your class doesn't sound like an enumerable thing, so I would get rid of the `IEnumerable<object>` interface.

Comment: @ArtK I think the class `MyClass` no needs to implements the interface IEnumerable<object>.

Comment: I removed IEnumerable provisions - still no luck with binding.

Comment: `myList.Add(new MyClass(1, "ABC");`   That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Post your real code.  You have obvious typing errors with what you are showing us (comboBox1 and comboBox, etc).

Comment: @Steve Wellens - okay, one missing ). It is an abstract not and actual code.

Comment: @ dbvega - thanks for your answer. I have 2 problems with it. 1. I don't understand how declaring a collection as var could work better than defining it as a strong type (List). 2. The way your collection gets its items would not work in my production code. My real life class is just an item for ComboList. I take a row from SQL db, add strings together to form DisplayItem and use primary key as ValueMember. That way I make db record usable for user and identifiable for db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass {SecondProperty = 1, FirstProperty = "ABC"},
    new MyClass {SecondProperty = 2, FirstProperty = "ZXC"}
};

comboBox1.DataSource = myList;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "FirstProperty";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SecondProperty";
```

I hope it helps.